# systemd-networkd does not create vxlan interface on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, networking, systemd-networkd

I want to define a VXLAN interface using `systemd-networkd` on an Ubuntu 22.04.

Therefore, I've created the following 2 files and ran `systemctl restart systemd-networkd`.

```
# /etc/systemd/network/my-vxlan.netdev

[NetDev]
Name=myvxlan
Kind=vxlan

[VXLAN]
VNI=5000
DestinationPort=4789
# IP of host system
Local=192.168.0.5
# IP of remote system
Remote=192.168.0.6
```

```
# /etc/systemd/network/my-vxlan.network
[Match]
# this interface should be used for in-/outbound VXLAN packages
Name=eth0

[Network]
VXLAN=myvxlan
# IP Address of this host on the VXLAN interface
Address=192.168.1.1/24
# Gateway IP of the VXLAN interface
Gateway=192.168.1.1
```

Unfortunately, the interface does not show up. `networkctl` only lists me the default interfaces:

```
IDX LINK TYPE     OPERATIONAL SETUP
  1 lo   loopback carrier     unmanaged
  2 eth0 ether    routable    configured

2 links listed.
```

In the logs, I can actually see the configuration was found:

```
> journalctl -u systemd-networkd.service |grep myvxlan
systemd-networkd[1805]: myvxlan: loaded vxlan
```

It seems to be related to the network definition. If I added the `Independent=yes` parameter to the `my-vxlan.netdev` file, the interface is created, but the network configuration was not applied.

I know that Ubuntu uses `netplan`, but as that one uses `networkd` as backend, it should all work, right?

Do you have any idea how I can accomplish this setup?